# How to check if an object is specular or diffuse

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, textures, rendering

what I am trying to do is developing my own path tracer. Actually I am using a framework provided by my professor in c++, which is a really basic path tracer. What I have to do is applying a new gradient domain algorithm by modifying this path tracer and checking the results. According to the algorithm I have sometimes to check if the object that I am hitting is specular or diffuse. 
The paper explicitly says:
***We classify all path vertices as either specular, or non-specular, based on a threshold on the roughness of the BRDF***. What I don't know to do is how to check it out. According to the framework a Material is specified like this:

```
public:
// constructor / destructor
Material();
~Material();
// get / set
void SetName( const char* _Name );
char* GetName() { return name; }
void SetColor( vec3 _Color ) { color = _Color; }
vec3& GetColor() { return color; }
void SetTexture( Texture* _Texture ) { texture = _Texture; }
Texture* GetTexture() { return texture; }
void SetNormalMap( Texture* _Normals ) { normalMap = _Normals; }
Texture* GetNormalMap() { return normalMap; }
void SetIndex( int _Idx ) { idx = _Idx; }
int GetIndex() { return idx; }
// methods
void Init( char* _Texture );
void Init( char* _Texture, char* _NormalMap = 0 );
// data members
```

private:
    Texture* texture;
    Texture* normalMap;
    vec3 color;
    char* name;
    int idx;
};

and a Texture is an object defined like:

```
class Texture
{
public:
// constructor / destructor
Texture();
Texture( const char* _File );
~Texture();
// get / set
uint GetID() { return id; }
void SetID( uint _ID ) { id = _ID; }
void SetName( const char* _Name );
char* GetName() { return name; }
bool HasAlpha() { return hasAlpha; }
void SetAlpha( bool _Alpha ) { hasAlpha = _Alpha; }
// methods
void Load( const char* _File );
void sRGBtoLinear( unsigned char* _Data, uint _Size, uint _Stride );
// data members
uint id, width, height;
uint* idata;
float* fdata;
char* name;
bool hasAlpha;
```

};

Now, according to this data, how can I check out if the material is diffuse or specular?

Comment: The Material interface has none of the information that would be needed to render a specular material so it looks like your professor's code only handles diffuse BRDFs. I would ask your professor for clarification if he wants you to handle specular. If he does you would need to modify the material definition.

Comment: @mattnewport ok thanks! just to understand: which are the info that I would need to handle specular materials?